# Meta tags not updated when using React-Helmet

Tags: reactjs, react-native, meta-tags, react-helmet

I build a website with react native.
In my index.html I have this in my `<head>`

```
<title>Sitetitle | Site USP</title>
<meta name="description" content="My site description" data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword for my website" data-react-helmet="true" />
```

In another page (aboutUs.js) I added helmet like this:

```
<Helmet>
<title>About us | Site USP</title> 
<meta name="description" content="This is the description for about us page"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="about us" />
</Helmet>
```

But the meta tags are not overwritten for some reason. Can anyone maybe explain if I am doing something wrong? In first place I didn't have `data-react-helmet="true"` added to my meta tags and read on stackoverflow to add them but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Do you need those meta tags in your `index.html`? Why not control all meta tags via helmet?